# Entity Framework - Insert row without auto increment

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, data-annotations, entity-framework-migrations

We got a database with Customers with ID's from 1-30000 in a ERP-system. Now we're creating a new website and we want to import some of the existing customers into the website but not all. Right now the primary key in Customer table on the website is of type int with Auto Increment that starts from 600001 to prevent any id collision.

We got three ideas:

1. Disable identity and insert the Customer then turn identity back on to prevent their id from being replaced.
2. Keep identity ON and generate a new Id to the imported ERP Customers and then place their old id in a different column in the table as a reference, because that's their customer number. New customers that are registered have no value in the CustomerNumber column since they are not imported, is there a way to automatically set the CustomerNumber same as the Id when we call db.SaveChanges() to prevent two calls to the database?
3. Disable identity and every time a new customer is created we make a db call to get the next id.

Some code:

```
var customer = new CustomerDto()
{
       Id = 6000,
       Type = CustomerDto.CustomerType.Company,
       Company = "Company",
       Ssn = "1234567890",
       FirstName = "Firstname",
       LastName = "Lastname",
       Email = "email@email.com"
}
db.Customers.Add(customer);
db.SaveChanges();
```

*EDIT*

Some of you suggested go for option 1. And this is what i tried:

```
 var db = new SsfContext(true);
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ON");
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

That didn't work. I also tried to add this to the OnModelCreating method but this gives me the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'MyContext'
>   context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerDto>()
                    .Property(x => x.Id)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

This is how the dto looks like:

```
[Table("Customer")]
    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Customer Type
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
        public CustomerType Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Either Corporate identity or social security number
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
        public string Ssn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Number 1 is the only good idea.

Comment: Definitely number 1!

Comment: If we'll go for nr 1, do you have any ideas how to do this using EF?